# The intergral $I=\int _0^{\beta }f(x)dx$ is given,for $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}$ ,how can we find $\int_0^{\alpha\beta}f(x)dx$ in terms of $I$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

i am working with a gaussian normal distribution function in probability,i am given values for the integral when $z\le 4$ and i want to find a value $z=8$,in general if $z=4$ is given ,
how to find the value when 
$z=4\alpha $

$I(z)=\large \int _0^z\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$

now i want to find

$I(2z)=\large \int _0^{2z}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$ in terms of $I(z)$

so i make a substitution

$t=2x$

$I(2z)=\large \frac{1}{2}\int _0^{z}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}\frac{1}{4}}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int _0^{z}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}(e^{\frac{1}{4}})^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt$

and it seems like i cannot arrive at the integral $I(z)$

Comment: I maybe wrong but I don't think there is a way.

Comment: it seems like the only way to connect index is $\int _{a_0}^{a_1} f(x)dx+\int _{a_1}^{a_2} f(x)dx+...+\int _{a_n-1}^{a_n} f(x)dx=\int _{a_0}^{a_n} f(x)dx $

Comment: if $f(x)=k$ then $I=\int _0^{\alpha} kdx$  
then $I(\alpha\beta)=\int _0^{\alpha\beta} kdx=\beta\int _0^{\alpha} kdx=\beta I$

Comment: my next problem was , is there a sequence $c_n$ that will describe the partitions of $f(x)$ as to give equal areas or probability $P_i$,between $ c_i$ and $c_j,i,j=1,2,...n,i,j\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $ \int _{c_i}^{c_j}f(x)dx=P_i$

Comment: i set $P_i=P$ in the previous work and also we have $\large \int _0^{c_n}f(x)dx=nP$

Comment: i have a feeling this will reduce us to Riemann's partitions

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is no way to express $I(2z)$ in terms of $I(z)$ in general, using only usual functions. If the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) $\mathrm{erf}$, however, is considered as a *usual function*, then $I(z)=\frac12\mathrm{erf}(z/\sqrt2)$ for every $z$, hence
$$
I(2z)=\tfrac12\mathrm{erf}(2\cdot\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(2I(z))).
$$
Likewise, for every $\alpha$, 
$$
I(\alpha z)=\tfrac12\mathrm{erf}(\alpha\cdot\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(2I(z))).
$$
As you can see, these are mere tautologies...